# List view add item to bottom(android)

Tags: android, xml, listview

Sorry for my english. In standart list view new item add to top, but i want add new item to bottom listView. Like this:

[image]

How i cant do like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add following line in your java file

```
listview.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

As per Android developer website **"When stack from bottom is set to true, the list fills its content starting from the bottom of the view"**.

Answer (score 4):

You just add your new items to the the other side of your data source. I thought new items get added to the bottom but might be wrong. Anyway, so for example, if you're using a list to store this data:

Simply instead of adding with

```
list.add(object)
```

use this

```
list.add(0, object)
```

and it will be added at the beginning of your data source

Comment: many many thanks, nothing worked for me, but your second approach! struggled for 3 days!